# Django: Unique_Together

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

My Django form allows teachers to choose which period they would like to request a student, "Academic Period 1" or "Academic Period 2" or "Both Periods". I currently have a unique_together option working perfectly for "Academic Period 1" and "Academic Period 2" where a duplicate request is not allowed, but how do I make the option named "Both Periods" block future submissions requesting periods "Academic Period 1" and "Academic Period 2"? See my code below. In the model, these choices are options for the field "Period".

**MODEL**

class RequestAStudent(models.Model):

```
PERIODS=(
    ('Academic Network 1', 'Academic Networking 1'),
    ('Academic Network 2', 'Academic Networking 2'),
    ('Both Periods', 'Both Periods'),
)
MARK=(
    ('None', 'None'),
    ('Present', 'Present'),
    ('Tardy', 'Tardy'),
    ('X', 'X'),
    ('Absent', 'Absent'),
)
student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
Requesting_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(AdvisoryTeacher, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
Period = models.CharField(max_length=18, null=True, choices = PERIODS)
teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, verbose_name='Advisory Teacher',default="None", on_delete= models.CASCADE)
date_requested = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Date for Student Request (Use format MMDDYY)', default="2021-11-04",null=True)
attendance = models.CharField(verbose_name='UPDATE ATTENDANCE HERE!',max_length=18, default="None",choices = MARK) #null=True, blank=True,
owner = models.IntegerField("Request Owner", blank=False, default=1)


def __str__(self):
        return "" + str(self.student) + ", Teacher: " + str(self.owner)
class Meta:
    unique_together = ["student", "Period", "date_requested"]
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand you want to check if the user choose both and prevent him from choosing first or second try this

```
def check_periods(obj,date,student,period):
    obj_with_same_dates = type(obj).objects.filter(date=date,student=student)
    if any(obj.period=="Academic Network 1" or obj.period=="Academic Network 2" for obj in obj_with_same_dates) and period=="Both Periods":
        return False
    return True
```

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    if not check_periods(self,self.date_requested,self.student,self.Period):
        return False
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Do I add this above the __str__ function? Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: Also, how does the length greater than 0 work? Will this still allow for Academic Periods 1 and 2 to be chosen for a student or only one or the options? Students can be chosen for Academic Period 1 and/or Academic Period 2 but not either of those periods if Both Periods is selected. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MarkYoung sorry for this mistake i wasn't focusing try this now

Comment: def check_periods(obj,date,student,period):
    obj_with_same_dates = type(obj).objects.filter(date=date,student=student)
    if any(obj.period=="Academic Network 1" or obj.period=="Academic Network 2" 
           for obj in obj_with_same_dates) and period=="Both Periods":
        return False
    elif any(obj.period=="Both Periods" for obj in obj_with_same_dates) and 
            period=="Academic Period 1" or "Academic Period 2":
           return False
    return True

Comment: Would my above comment be correct if I wanted to add prevention for someone wanting to choose an individual period if "Both Periods" has already been chosen?

Comment: OK, I have added these functions but I cannot call the first one inside of the second one. Thanks again for all of your help!!!

Comment: I have studied and research Model class methods and am still stumped on how to make this work. Can anyone help?